# Can I write, 'I found sick children among ostensibly normal schoolboys'

Tags: meaning

Can I write, 'I found sick children among ostensibly normal schoolboys'; is it the same as   'I found sick children among apparently normal schoolboys'

Comment: Stick with `apparantly`. `Ostensibly` connotes a hidden purpose, which wouldn't make sense here.

Comment: Or 'I found sick children among schoolboys reckoned to be healthy.' might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree that *apparently* is preferable to *ostensibly*, but I feel the sentence has another issue.

The combination of *sick* with *ostensibly normal* suggests some form of mental illness, as opposed to *sick = ill* in the physical sense. *normal* being, in my understanding, the opposite of *strange* or *abnormal*.

Answer (score -1):

"I found sick children among ostensibly **healthy** schoolboys",  is a much better way to put it; as antonym of ***sick*** is ***healthy/well,*** not ***normal.***